# Roll a 7, move robber AND play knight and move the robber again in the same turn

Tags: catan

Lately while playing Catan I've been in situation of rolling a 7 and having a knight development card in my hand.

Is it legal for me to move the robber due to the 7 and then play a knight and move the robber again all in the same turn?

Comment: What about one of two knights activate after using warlord card wih robber?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that is legal. You may play the knight at any time during your turn, including before rolling.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can. There is no restriction on playing a Knight card if you have already moved the Robber via a roll of '7'. From the [Rulebook](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf).

> b) Playing Development Cards - At any time during your turn, you play one Development Card (on the table). That card, however, may not be a card that you bought during the same turn!
>
> Knight (aka Soldier) Cards (red frame) - If you play a Knight Card, you must immediately move the robber. See "Rolling a '7' and Activating the Robber" above and follow steps 1 and 2.

Comment: I would add that in the Cities and Knights variant, this can be a particularly nasty tactic, since you can bounce the robber around a number of times.  In competitive games, I love to do so if I get an early metropolis (and no other cities) to deactivate my knights when the barbarians are close to landing.

Answer (score 6):

It is legal. But to add to what others have said, sometimes it may be advantageous for you to play a knight card before you roll.

Let's say the robber occupies a land tile connected to one of your cities or settlements. By playing your knight card and moving the robber you get to collect any cards that the robber would have otherwise blocked, or deny your opponents any cards they may have otherwise collected.

Otherwise, if you roll first, and you roll a number that's occupied by the robber, you lose any cards that you would have otherwise collected if you played the knight card (and moved the robber) before you rolled.

Comment: Furthermore, you open up the possibility of the target hex producing for your opponents if/when you wait till after rolling. (Of course, maybe you're hoping to steal said resource with the robber, but it's better to just deprive the opponent of the opportunity, IMO)